# How can I do the same view in different phone screens?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am designing my android project on android studio. I used horizontal Linear Layout however it looks exactly the same as I wanted to be in Nexus 5, when I run the project on Nexus S, the view distorted. How can I fix this?

**In nexus 5 view,**

[image: nexus_5]

**In nexus S view,**

[image: nexus_s]

**My xml file,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="97dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Duygu Yeşim"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Kullanıcı Adı : "
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dygysm"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:textColor="@color/light_blue"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E-mail Adresi :"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_design2"
                android:hint="duygu.yesim@hotmail.com"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Doğum Tarihi : "
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dogum_tarihi"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_birtday_design"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/calendar"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="310dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bildirimler"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:id="@+id/switch1" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Şifre Değiştirme"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_orange"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="310dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:background="@color/light_blue"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="87dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_kaydet_buton"
                android:id="@+id/button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="87dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_cikis_buton"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/34996396/2826147

Comment: Don't use Fixed `Width and Height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You will need to create multiple XML files as per screen sizes, Check this documentation - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

or

2) Put your Linear Layout in Horizontal Scroll View

Hope it will help :)